# Using sandwich theorem to show convergence

Tags: calculus

I have arbitrary functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that have a following property.
$$x>f(x)>g(x)$$
And I know that as $x  \rightarrow \infty $,$g(x) \rightarrow \infty $, thus by sandwich theorem,i can say $f(x) \rightarrow \infty $
Now I have following integral
$$\int^x_{f(x)} \cdot \, dy$$ from here,can I say that this integral converges to $0$,as $x  \rightarrow \infty $? 
As we know $x$ and $f(x) $ goes to infinity and when upper bound and lower bound are the same, integral is zero.

Comment: What is the argument for the integral, or is it just $\int_{f(x)}^x dy$?

Comment: One can say roughly nothing about the integral as currently described.   Certainly it need not approach $0$. For example, let $f(x)=x/2$ for large $x$.

Comment: That is not a viable conclusion.  $x-f(x)$ is of indeterminate form ($\infty -\infty$).  So, without further information, we can not deduce anything about convergence or lack thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x) = x-1$ and $g(x) = x-2$ (I am assuming these are real functions with real domains and codomains). Then certainly $x > f(x) > g(x)$ and, as $x \to \infty$, both $f(x),g(x) \to \infty$ exactly as in your question. However, for any real $x$, $$\int_{f(x)}^x dy = \int_{x-1}^x dy = 1$$ Thus, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \int_{f(x)}^x dy = 1$ also.

Comment: Yes!  Well done.  +1

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, take $f(x)=x-\ln{x}$. (The integral is just equal to $x-f(x)$)

Comment: How is this a counterexample since $x-f\ =1/x^2\to 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I have updated my answer.